# Value of type ’String’ cannot be converted to ’System.Drawing.Image’

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, picturebox

In my form, i have a datagridview, 4 textboxes for id, firstname, lastname. Middlename and a picturebox which will display and image once i select a certain row in datagridview. I want to display the image in picturebox when i click a certain row .I have a code for this  But i got this error.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim r As DataRow = Access.DBDT.Rows(0)

    txtDelID.Text = r("ID").ToString
    txtDelCourse.Text = r("Course").ToString
    txtDelFname.Text = r("FirstName").ToString
    txtDelLname.Text = r("LastName").ToString
    txtDelMname.Text = r("MiddleName").ToString
    pbDisplay.Image = r("Avatar").ToString

    msiDeleteStud.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what part of the error message is confusing?  the `PictureBox.Image` requires an `Image` type and you are explicitly assigning a string: `r("Avatar").ToString`

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
Dim r As DataRow = Access.DBDT.Rows(0)

Dim byteImage() As Byte = r.Item("Avatar")
Dim MStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteImage)
pbDisplay.Image = Image.FromStream(MStream)
txtDelID.Text = r("ID").ToString
txtDelCourse.Text = r("Course").ToString
txtDelFname.Text = r("FirstName").ToString
txtDelLname.Text = r("LastName").ToString
txtDelMname.Text = r("MiddleName").ToString

msiDeleteStud.Enabled = True
```